# Issues connecting to a Google Cloud SQL instance from Google Cloud Run

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a postgresql Google Cloud SQL instance and I'm trying to connect a FastAPI application running in Google Cloud Run to it, however I'm getting `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` errors.

My application uses the [databases](https://pypi.org/project/databases/) package for async database connections:

```
database = databases.Database(sqlalchemy_database_uri)
```

Which then tries to connect on app startup through:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup() -> None:
    if not database.is_connected:
        await database.connect() <--- this is where the error is raised
```

From reading through the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) it suggests forming the connection string like so:

```
"postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@/dbname?unix_sock=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

I've tried several different variations of the url, with `host` instead of `unix_sock` as the [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#unix-domain-connections) seem to suggest, as well as removing the `.s.PGSQL.5432` at the end as I've seen some other SO posts suggest, all to no avail.

I've added the Cloud SQL connection to the instance in the Cloud Run dashboard and added a Cloud SQL Client role to the service account.

I'm able to connect to the databases locally with the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy.

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to fix this, or even how to debug it as there doesn't seem to be any easy way to ssh into container and try out some things. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm able to connect directly with sqlalchemy with:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(url)
engine.connect()
```

Where url is any of these formats:

```py
"postgresql://user:pass@/db_name?host=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME"
"postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@/db_name?host=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME"
"postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@/db_name?unix_sock=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Is there something due to `databases`'s async nature that's causing issues?

Comment: Does  your database have a public IP?

Comment: it does yep @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Why would the public IP matter? Since this should be Unix socket.

Answer (score 1):

turns out this was a bug with the `databases` package. this should now be resolved with https://github.com/encode/databases/pull/423